# Fill an Excel Cell With Two Colors defined by ColorIndex

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fill a cell with two colors. I understand I can use Gradient.ColorStops like so

```
       With Range("B1").Interior
            .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
            .Gradient.Degree = 90
            
            'Adjust Color Stops
                'Clear Default Color Stops
                    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
                
                'Add A Color Stop
                    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
                        .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                    End With
                
                'Add Another Color Stop
                    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
                        .Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    End With
        End With
```

However I need color to be defined by ColorIndex, and I need a clear cut between the two colors. So it will look like this but in one cell. Is that possible?

[image]

Comment: I don't believe that's possible with a gradient fill.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by merge other cell, but choose not to merge the cell that you would like to have split of color, it seem like the only possible solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The case you are describing isn´t possible in this way. The solution of Kin Siang might be viable, but if you want to write in the cells i think there is a better way.

```
'Making two arrays for the rgb colors
Dim gradientRGB1(0, 2) As Integer
Dim gradientRGB2(0, 2) As Integer
'Saving the background color of the dummy cells
color1 = Range("A1").Interior.Color
color2 = Range("A2").Interior.Color
'Setting the dummy cells to the colorindexes of the gradient
Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
Range("A2").Interior.ColorIndex = 2
'Getting the colors for the gradient in excel color format
gradientcolor1 = Range("A1").Interior.Color
gradientcolor2 = Range("A2").Interior.Color
'Calculating the rgb values and inserting in the rgb arrays
gradientRGB1(0, 0) = gradientcolor1 Mod 256
gradientRGB1(0, 1) = ((gradientcolor1 \ 256) Mod 256)
gradientRGB1(0, 2) = (gradientcolor1 \ 65536)
gradientRGB2(0, 0) = gradientcolor2 Mod 256
gradientRGB2(0, 1) = ((gradientcolor2 \ 256) Mod 256)
gradientRGB2(0, 2) = (gradientcolor2 \ 65536)
With Range("B1").Interior
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 90
    
    'Adjust Color Stops
    'Clear Default Color Stops
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    
    'Add A Color Stop
    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .Color = RGB(gradientRGB1(0, 0), gradientRGB1(0, 1), gradientRGB1(0, 2))
    End With
    
    'Add two Stops to generate an edge
    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.499999)
        .Color = RGB(gradientRGB1(0, 0), gradientRGB1(0, 1), gradientRGB1(0, 2))
    End With
    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.5)
        .Color = RGB(gradientRGB2(0, 0), gradientRGB2(0, 1), gradientRGB2(0, 2))
    End With
        
    'Add Another Color Stop
    With .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .Color = RGB(gradientRGB2(0, 0), gradientRGB2(0, 1), gradientRGB2(0, 2))
    End With
End With
'Reset the colors of the dummy cells
Range("A1").Interior.Color = color1
Range("A2").Interior.Color = color2
```

You will need two dummy cells wich will be filled with the colorindex colors of your gradient, it will be reseted at the end. Its not possible to make gradients with colorindexes but you can fill a cell with this colorindex, get the colorcode and calculate the rgb values. So its a workarround.
To achieve the hard edge you need two colorstops very close to each other that you can´t see the gardient between them.